# How to handle HTTP CONNECT tunnel on client side?

Tags: sockets, http, https, lua, tunnel

I am adding support for HTTP CONNECT request to a client and I can't seem to handle the tunnel properly.

I am able to send a CONNECT request to the proxy which response with a status code of 200. This [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2817.txt) tell me that the tunnel has been formed with the end server.

How do I use this tunnel from a socket perspective? 
On the client side, the socket I opened receives the 200 response from proxy initially. After checking the response should I just send more data into that socket?
I tried this approach and the client just hangs. The data doesn't seem to reach the final server. How to use this socket to do normal HTTP(S) after the tunnel is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After checking the response should I just send more data into that socket?

Yes. If you are speaking HTTPS you now start a TLS handshake and then send a properly formed HTTP request and read the response, both via TLS.

> I tried this approach and the client just hangs. The data doesn't seem to reach the final server.

So either your handshake was wrong or your HTTP was malformed.

Comment: I am still investigating the pcap files. Would inform of the correct solution once I am done.

Comment: The 'correct solution' is to fix your code. As you haven't posted it, what other answer is possible?

Comment: Yeah. I fixed it now and it was a problem with the order in which I sent headers and request lines. HTTP was malformed in a sense and I think I can mark yours as right answer